# Let Σ = { a; b} How can I define a PDA in JFLAP which recognizes the following?

Tags: formal-languages, automaton, pushdown-automaton, jflap

L = {a^n b^k | 2n >= k}

For example.: abb  is element of L, aabbb is element of L, ε is element of L, but babbb is not element of L, abbb is not element of L

Comment: Look, StackOverflow is not a homework site. At the very least, you should show your efforts so far. Or just today, you could try asking the duck.

Comment: IF I could even start it, i would have shown it. Trust me.... I dont have a clue

Answer (score 0):

The shortest string in `L` is the empty string, `e`. Given a string `s` in the language, the following rules hold:

1. `as` is in `L`
2. `asb` is in `L`
3. `asbb` is in `L`

We can combine these observations to get a context-free grammar:

```
S := aSbb | aSb | aS | e
```

By our observations, every string generated by this grammar must be in `L`. To show that this is a grammar for `L`, we must show that any string in `L` can be generated. To get a string `a^n b^k` we can do the following:

1. use rule #1 above `x` times
2. use rule #2 above `y` times
3. use rule #3 above `z` times
4. ensure `x + y + z = n`
5. ensure `y + 2z = k`

Setting `y = k - 2z` and substituting we find `x + k - 2z + z = n`. Rearranging:

1. if `k > n`, then `z` and `x` can be chosen however desired so long as `k - n = z - x`.
2. if `k < n`, then `z` and `x` can be chosen however desired so long as `n - k = x - z`.
3. If `k = n`, observe we might as well just choose `y = n`.

Note that we can always choose `z` and `x` in our above example since `0 <= x, z <= n` and `0 <= k <= 2n`.